# Editing account questions

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts

Where in the account settings can you find (developer life), for which I am minus (moving through which menu items of the Stack Overflow website)?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about how to edit your developer story on Stack Overflow, you need to open your profile page by opening https://stackoverflow.com/users/current. Then, click on the "Developer Story" button in the header:

[image: Image of the profile page's "Developer Story" button, circled in red]

Alternatively, you can just navigate to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current